# Unable to route to child resource - Nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested

I've been banging my head against this one for few days now ......

my routes.rb file looks like this:

```
resources :vehicles do
 member do
   resources :services  
 end
end
```

my service.rb file shows:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle
end
```

my vehicle.rb file shows:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Here is services_controller.rb

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])
    @services = @vehicle.services.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def show
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])
    @service = Vehicle.services.find(params[:service_id])
  end

  def new
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])
    @service = @vehicle.services.new
  end 

  def create
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])
    @service = @vehicle.services.build(service_params)
    if @service.save
      redirect_to @vehicle
    else
      render :new
    end
  end


  private
    def service_params
       params.require(:service).permit(:service_option, :odometer, 
   :current_service, :price, :comments, :next_service)
  end

end
```

And here is the services#index

```
<h1>Services</h1>


<% @services.each do |s| %>
  <%= link_to "Details", service_path(s) %>
  <%= s.created_at %>
  <%= s.service_option %>
  <%= s.odometer %><br>
<% end %>
```

Clicking on the "Details" link or manually entering the URL

> http://localhost:3000/vehicles/2/services/7

gives my systematically the same routing error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ServicesController#show
>     Couldn't find Vehicle with 'id'=7

```
Extracted source (around line #10):

def show
   @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])
   @service = Vehicle.services.find(params[:service_id])
end
```

It passes a SERVICE ID to a vehicle objet / variable and I don't know why!

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `services#show` method you are fetching the `vehicle` and `service` with **wrong params**. Also `Vehicle.services` is wrong, it should be `@vehicle.services`

```
def show
  @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id])
  @service = @vehicle.services.find(params[:id])
end
```

***Update:***

You should remove `member` in the routes, else it will produce the routes like

```
service GET  /vehicles/:id/services/:id(.:format)  services#show
```

which are **irrelevant**

```
resources :vehicles do
  resources :services  
end
```

So now you will have routes like

```
service GET  /vehicles/:vehicle_id/services/:id(.:format)  services#show
```

which are relevant and you can fetch the vehicle with `params[:vehicle_id]` and service with `params[:id]`

Don't forget to change the *route helpers*. For instance `service_path` will become `vehicle_service_path`

```
<%= link_to "Details", vehicle_service_path(@vehicle,s) %>
```

Comment: Pavan, Thanks for answering my question. This completely makes sense now and working fine. Your help is much appreciated!